# What happens when the owner kills a multisig wallet?

Tags: wallets, multisignature, smart-contract-wallets

if the owner decide to kill a multisig wallet (Smart Contract),

1. Is he/she will be able to do kill the contract?
2. If so where does the ether get deposited to?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By default there is no such concept as *contract owner*. Such concept exists only if it has been coded into the contract.

So it depends on what kind of functionality the contract has.

If by *killing* you mean `selfdestruct`, then the `selfdestruct` function requires an `address` parameter which specifies to which address all remaining Ethers are sent.